# DNS and DHCP on different machines

Tags: networking, router, dns, dhcp

I have a router (Vodafone easy box) which doesn't seem to support local DNS. Now i want to set up my own DNS server on another machine, but still want to use DHCP. So I want to setup my DNS server to resolve DNS names to dynamic IP addresses which are managed by the router. The DNS server would run on Debian jessie.

Is this possible or do I need switch the DHCP to my Debian server too? Does anyone know a good guide how to do this?

I already searched about this but only found manuals describing how to setup DNS and DHCP on the same machine, but i think my case is a little bit different.

Comment: You can set DNS servers separately from dhcp-received settings, how depends on the OS.

Comment: Which OS? The OS of the clients, of the DHCP server or of the DNS server?

Comment: The OS of the clients.

Comment: The clients are running on Debian, Windows 7, Windows 8 and Windows XP.

Comment: I've provided an answer, hope it's clear. Merry Christmas btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up your DNS server and configure it with static ip. Then configure all your clients to use this DNS server, and not the one provided by DHCP.

- Debian: [you'll find a clear and short explanation plus how-to here](http://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Defining_the_.28DNS.29_Nameservers) as this depends on how your network settings are managed.
- Windows 7/8: Go to `Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections`. Right-click on the interface(s) you're using to connect to the network ("Wireless Network Connection" or "Local Area Connection") and select `Properties`. Double-click on `Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)`.
   The folowing screen is divided into two parts, with each a choice to *"Obtain ... automatically"* or *"Use the following ..."*. The bottom part is used for DNS configuration, select *"Use the following DNS server addresses:*" and provide the IP address you configured for your DNS server. Click OK.
- Windows XP: Go to `Control Panel > Network Connections` and select your local network. Click `Properties`, then select `Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)`. Click `Properties`. After this it's the same story as with Windows 7/8, select `Use the following DNS server addresses:` and provide the IP address you configured for your DNS server. Click OK.

Comment: But if i got this right, i need to list every client which is in the DNS domain in the zone file. But the clients don't have static ip addresses, so i can't list them.

Comment: So if you have a laptop and desktop for example, you want to access them by typing laptop.local and desktop.local instead of their respective IP addresses? Then you'd have to set up some sort of dyndns system, or just configure all of them with static IP's and define them statically in the zone file. The latter would be the simplest way to accomplish what you want. (This doesn't mean dhcp would be off in your network, you can have it on for guests.)